# Trying to Export data from Prometheus to CSV using Python script

Tags: python, prometheus

I have a below python script(yprom_csv.py) aailable and trying to pass prometheus url,
getting error.

```
`import csv
import requests
import sys
def GetMetrixNames(url):
    response = requests.get('{0}/api/v1/label/__name__/values'.format(url))
    names = response.json()['data']
    #Return metrix names
    return names
"""
Prometheus hourly data as csv.
"""
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('Usage: {0} http://localhost:9090'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)
metrixNames=GetMetrixNames(sys.argv[1])
writeHeader=True
for metrixName in metrixNames:
     #now its hardcoded for hourly
     response = requests.get('{0}/api/v1/query'.format(sys.argv[1]),
     params={'query': metrixName+'[1h]'})
     results = response.json()['data']['result']
     # Build a list of all labelnames used.
     #gets all keys and discard __name__
     labelnames = set()
      for result in results:
          labelnames.update(result['metric'].keys())
      # Canonicalize
      labelnames.discard('__name__')
      labelnames = sorted(labelnames)
      # Write the samples.
      if writeHeader:
          writer.writerow(['name', 'timestamp', 'value'] + labelnames)
          writeHeader=False
      for result in results:
          l = [result['metric'].get('__name__', '')] + result['values']
          for label in labelnames:
              l.append(result['metric'].get(label, ''))
              writer.writerow(l)`
```

Run Command:
python3 yprom_csv.py https://prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.XXXX-    XXXXXXX.Xx8X.p1.openshiftapps.com

Getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/yprom_csv.py", line 16, in <module>
metrixNames=GetMetrixNames(sys.argv[1])
File "/root/yprom_csv.py", line 6, in GetMetrixNames
names = response.json()['data']
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response content is not a valid JSON format. Try debugging the response.

You can check the content type with:

```
response.headers.get('content-type')
```

You can check the content with:

```
response.content
```

I also like to check the response code before doing anything else.

```
def GetMetrixNames(url):
    response = requests.get('{0}/api/v1/label/__name__/values'.format(url))
    if response.ok:
        names = response.json()['data']
        #Return metrix names
        return names
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: the url that I am passing is correct? 
https://prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.XXXX- XXXXXXX.Xx8X.p1.openshiftapps.com

I do not understand the difference between above and "http://localhost:9090'"

Comment: @yugenreddy, localhost:9090 is the address to access the tool on the server it is running on. If you're not running the script on the same machine, you need to use a different address.
Try to debug what is returned (the content in response) with the current URL and go from there.